# Spring soap ws is not running with the request having no namespace prefix in xml tags

Tags: spring-boot, soap

I have a already generated wsdl file which i am using to write a springboot soap ws but when i load that wsdl file in soapUi to create a request to test my ws i get a request which has nested tags missing with namespace prefix. On triggering that request, springboot is giving saaj soap exception with 404 error due to the non prefixed tag.

When I added the namespace prefix to all the tags manually the ws worked properly.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://webservice.studentinfo.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:studentData>
         <student>
               <name>?</name>
               <roll_number>?</roll_number>
               <address>
                  <house_number>?</house_number>
                  <street>?</street>
                  <city>?</city>
                  <state>?</state>
               </address>
            </student>
    </web:studentData>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

If i add "web:" in all the nested tags inside  tag my ws is working as expected but for above request its not. since i cant change wsdl format as its an output of some third party application, is there any way, by invoking this request itself i shall get my ws working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add specific mapper your configuration like that

```
public class MyNamespaceMapper extends NamespacePrefixMapper {

private static final String FOO_PREFIX = ""; // DEFAULT NAMESPACE
private static final String FOO_URI = "http://www.example.com/FOO";

private static final String BAR_PREFIX = "bar";
private static final String BAR_URI = "http://www.example.com/BAR";

@Override
public String getPreferredPrefix(String namespaceUri, String suggestion, boolean requirePrefix) {
    if(FOO_URI.equals(namespaceUri)) {
        return FOO_PREFIX;
    } else if(BAR_URI.equals(namespaceUri)) {
        return BAR_PREFIX;
    }
    return suggestion;
}

@Override
public String[] getPreDeclaredNamespaceUris() {
    return new String[] { FOO_URI, BAR_URI };
}

}
```

You can follow this [tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/jaxb-and-namespace-prefixes). However, it can be problem for the spring ws you need to add this configuration spring ws.